# From the webjob's perspective, how to detect that the website stopped?

Tags: azure-webjobs

This is for the scheduled webjobs.

When we stop the website in the portal, the webjobs view is disabled (saying that it can only be displayed when the website is started), but the webjobs are still running.

How can I detect programmatically that the website stopped?

Thanks in advance.